# Does the base damage stat matter for the weapon?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

So I have a lightsaber I bought on the Cartel Market and I put some lv65 mods into it so that it was helpful at my level.

However during my play I have had another lightsaber drop for me which is the same level of 65, but has a huge boost to the base damage numbers.

[image: Ardent Defenders Lightsaber vs Outlander Vigilant Saber]

As you can see, they both share the same item rating of 210, but the stats very wildly between the Cartel Market item I have added mods to and the regular loot item.

Considering the difference in the raw damage stat am I losing out by using my Cartel Market saber? Or is there a mod or enhancement I'm missing to boost the base damage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the reason the base dmg numbers are different was due to level scaling. I was completing a mission on Hoth which reduced my level from 70 to 41.

The scaling had changed my weapons damage to match that level. Once I checked again on Fleet the base damage was the same.

[image]